# How do ifempty and notifempty work in case of size parameter defined in case of logrotate?

Tags: linux, logrotate

Suppose if I have a logrotate command like this

```
/a/b/file.log{
size 5M 
ifempty
}
```

Now the logrotate works on the condition that size should be more than 5MB and then logrotate will start working for that file. But how will ifempty work in this case? What will be the precedence in this case? And what about the case of notifempty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setup:

- `size 5M` instructs `logrotate` to only rotate log files if they are larger than 5MB;
- `ifempty` instructs `logrotate` even if the log files are empty (this is enabled by default).

These directives can appear to conflict: a 0-byte file would be excluded by the first directive, but included by the second.

What happens in practice is that `ifempty` has no explicit effect on file selections; the significant “empty” setting is its opposite, `notifempty`, which disables rotation in all cases if a log file is empty. `ifempty` exists so that the default behaviour can be restored for a specific configuration when `notifempty` is set globally.

Another way to think about this is that `ifempty`/`notifempty` don’t select files, they only determine what happens if an empty log file is considered for rotation, after all other criteria have been applied. If `ifempty` is set (again, that’s the default), empty log files are rotated; if `notifempty` is set, they are not.

With your configuration, log files will only be rotated if they are larger than 5MB.

Comment: The size directive has a significant precedence over all the other directives right. Like it also overrides the rotation interval (daily, monthly, weekly) ?

Comment: Amazing answer btw.

Comment: No, I’m not saying anything about the precedence of `size` v. any other criteria; what I’m saying is that `ifempty`/`notifempty` is evaluated last, in all cases.

Comment: Sir can you please look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685430/what-should-be-the-preferred-approach-while-rotating-logs-using-the-daily-dire