# What should be the preferred approach while rotating logs - using the daily directive or putting the file path in cron.daily?

Tags: cron, logrotate

While doing log rotation, we have two options -

1. Using the daily directive in the logrotate file -

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    daily
    minsize 1M
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

2. Putting the logrotation  file path in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`

Which method is the preferred method and what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Also if both of them are used together what will be the impact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` and rotation configuration files serve different purposes.

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` ensures that `logrotate`, the tool, is run once a day (if the system is up). It also determines the configuration file that is read, `/etc/logrotate.conf`. Since the latter typically includes files in `/etc/logrotate.d`, you generally don’t need to modify it to add new configuration files — instead, add the configuration files to `/etc/logrotate.d`.

The rotation configuration files determine what happens to each managed log file. This is largely independent of what `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` says; the main constraint added by the latter is that logs can’t be rotated more often than `logrotate` runs, so with the default daily setup, logs can’t be rotated more often than daily.

In typical setups, `logrotate` has a default setting to rotate logs weekly. If you want to change that, changing `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` won’t help; even if you made `logrotate` run every minute, it still would only rotate logs weekly. To change the frequency at which logs are rotated, you need to change the rotation configuration itself, either globally, or for each log file you want to rotate daily.

So the answer to your question is, to rotate log files daily, specify the `daily` directive in the relevant section of the rotation configuration.

Comment: Sure. Thanks got a lot of clarity. Individually specifying rotation configuration in each file inside /etc/logrotate.d is the way to go, right?

Comment: That depends; if you find yourself changing a setting in *every* file inside `/etc/logrotate.d`, you should make it a global setting in `/etc/logrotate.conf` instead. For individual files, yes, change the corresponding file in `/etc/logrotate.d`.