# Logrotate scenarios - Mix and match cron.daily and daily directive

Tags: cron, logrotate

The file:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

has the following statement:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

The `logrotate.conf` file has the `weekly` directive defined inside.

Now I have two rotational configuration files `abc` and `def` inside `/etc/logrotate.d`. `abc` has the `daily` directive inside it which to my knowledge will override the `weekly` directive in `/etc/logrotate.conf`. And `def` has no such directive so it will inherit the `weekly` directive from `/etc/logrotate.conf`.
Now my doubt is that `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` will run everyday and will check inside the
`/etc/logrotate.conf` file which in turn has the `include /etc/logrotate.d` directive inside. So in conclusion `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` will go through both `abc` and `def`. My question is what will be the actual frequency of logrotation for both `abc` and `def`? Will both of them be rotated daily or one daily and one weekly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried to explain in [What should be the preferred approach while rotating logs - using the daily directive or putting the file path in cron.daily?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/685430/86440), `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` is irrelevant as far as rotation frequencies are concerned, unless you’re trying to rotate more often than daily.

To determine what a given configuration is going to do, you can ask `logrotate` itself:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

won’t actually rotate anything, but it will tell you everything it considers and everything it would do. In particular, it will tell you what the rotation frequency for each pattern and file is.

Any `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly` etc. directive inside braces only applies to that pattern. So if `abc` has

```
/path/to/file.log {
    daily
    ...
}
```

it will cause the matching file(s) to be rotated daily, regardless of the global directive in `/etc/logrotate.conf` (if any). It won’t affect any other file.

If `def` doesn’t have a frequency directive, it will inherit the global setting.